# Concurrency in Erlang

Tags: concurrency, functional-programming, erlang

The problem I am trying to solve is as follows:

Write an Erlang function named squared that takes no parameters. This function should wait to receive a message. The message will be in the format { Pid, N }, where you may assume that Pid is a process ID and N is a number. The function should send a message to the process ID Pid in the form { Me, X } where Me is the process ID of the process running the function and X is the value of N squared. The function should then end.

so far I have this:

```
-module(main).
-export([squared/0]).

squared() ->
 receive
    {Pid,N} -> Pid ! {Me, X}, squared();
 terminate -> ok
 end.
```

The error that I am getting is as follows:

3> c(main).

main.erl:7: variable 'Me' is unbound

main.erl:7: variable 'X' is unbound

main.erl:7: Warning: variable 'N' is unused
error

I am also having trouble in the second part of the problem where it is asking us to send a message to the process ID in the form {Me, X}. Where Me is the process ID and X is the value of N squared. How will we do that?

Comment: In your description of the problem, the function `squared/0` should ends as soon as it replies to the message. Therefore you do not need the `terminate -> ok`, and as your function is not recursive, the process will die as soon as it sends its answer. Unbound means that the variable did not get a value when you try to use it. For a correct code, see @choroba 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

for implement your function you can write a function like bellow

```
-module(main).
-export([squared/0]).

squared() ->
 receive
    {Pid,N} -> 
        Pid ! {self(), N*N},
        squared();
    terminate -> 
    ok
 end.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Me` should be the pid of the receiving process, i.e. `self()`. N squared is just N*N.

```erlang
-module(main).
-export([squared/0]).

squared() ->
    receive
        {Pid, N} ->
            Pid ! {self(), N*N};
        terminate -> ok
    end.
```

Or, if you want to be more verbous:

```erlang
squared() ->
    Me = self(),
    receive
        {Pid, N} ->
            X = N * N,
            Pid ! {Me, X};
        terminate -> ok
    end.
```